# Search append and print in one line python3

Tags: python-3.x

I have data like this:

```
ice_cream 0.00013286998380339406

hot_chocolate 0.0002134821993051205

ice_cream -7.833574001019025e-05

hot_chocolate -0.0001492061779651939
```

I want to print out like this :

```
ice_cream 0.00013286998380339406 -7.833574001019025e-05

hot_chocolate 0.0002134821993051205 -0.0001492061779651939
```

I tried some things but does not work properly. How can I do this in python3?

Comment: What did you try so far? Please show us your code, so we can take a look at it to find your issue.

Comment: What's the input format - pandas, list, dict ?

Comment: What is source of input data?

Answer (score 0):

The best way would probably be to create a list for each variable and append the values to it.

```
# Creating the lists
ice_cream =[]
hot_chocolate = []

# Appending the values to the lists
# In practise you would use a loop here, that reads your source file and 
# then appends the value to the respective list
ice_cream.append(value1)
ice_cream.append(value2)

hot_chocolate.append(value3)
hot_chocolate.append(value4)

# printing out the values
print("ice_cream",ice_cream)
print("hot_chocolate",hot_chocolate)
```

which should return something like this:

```
ice_cream [0.00013286998380339406, -7.833574001019025e-05]
hot_chocolate [0.0002134821993051205, -0.0001492061779651939]
```

If it is very important that the output has no square brackets and commata, you can convert the list to a string and then use other methods to remove them.

```
print("hot_chocolate", " ".join(hot_chocolate))

>>> hot_chocolate 0.0002134821993051205 -0.0001492061779651939
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = open("combine.txt", 'r')
dic ={}
for line in data.readlines():
    line=line.strip("\n")
    if line:
        key,value = line.split(" ")
        if key in dic:
            dic[key].append(value)
        else:
            dic[key]=[]
            dic[key].append(value)
for k in dic.keys():
    print(str(k)," ".join(dic[k]))
data.close()
```

If your input is text file this is the solution of your problem, Hopefully it will work for you.